# Delete character after ':' but not delete the rest

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

For example my excel column is

```
CodeandPrice
3&12|4&200|2&
5&|2&
4&|
2&12|35&744
```

With `&` is separation between code and price, `|` is separation betweeen 2 item.
I want to only get the code, so character before &.

```
CodeandPrice
3&|4&|2&
5&|2&
4&|
2&|35&
```

I ve googled but what I found is remove all character after/before. But what I want is,
remove a character after & but not all, since there will be another code.

Comment: Is the Excel-2010 tag accurate?

Comment: I work in excel 2010, I shouldnt use the tag ?

Comment: Yes you should, but some people use the tag inapproriately and have newer versions of Excel available

Comment: Can you do a bulk *Find & Replace* on the cells using *Find what*: `&*|`, *Replace with*: `&|`?

Comment: @JosWoolley, I got excited as it appeared to work but it would leave `35&744` in the final sample untouched and it would also remove any pipe-symbols.

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, I was dubious to be honest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Excel 2010, maybe the easiest is to quickly throw together an UDF and invoke this as a function in your sheet, for example:

```
Function RegexReplace(s_in As String, pat As String, repl As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = pat
    RegexReplace = .Replace(s_in, repl)
End With

End Function
```

Invoke like: `=RegexReplace(A2,"\d+\|","")`

---

If one happens to have newer functionality available try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(a,"&","|"),,1)&"&")))
```